# Fixed nodes within parent with cytoscape

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to do something like this with Cytoscape.js: [image: diagram]

I want the modules to be draggable but the inner nodes must be fixed with relative position and not selectable. I couldn't find any solution to do that.  Thanks for your help!

I'm using this JSON structure:

```
elements: {
  nodes: [
     { data: { id: 'listener', name: 'Listener' } },
     { data: { id: 'listener-true', parent: 'listener', label: 'true' }, position: { x: 300, y: 55 } },
     { data: { id: 'listener-false', parent: 'listener', label: 'false' }, position: { x: 300, y: 85 } },
     { data: { id: 'configuration', name: 'Configuration' } },
     { data: { id: 'configuration-true', parent: 'configuration', label: 'true' }, position: { x: 100, y: 55 } },
     { data: { id: 'configuration-false', parent: 'configuration', label: 'false' }, position: { x: 100, y: 85 } },
  ],
  edges: [
     { data: { id: 'ad', source: 'configuration-true', target: 'listener' } }      
  ]
}
```

Comment: what's the code to reproduce the depicted graph rendering?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Cytoscape implementation?

Comment: whatever code that was used to generate the images — was it Cytoscape or Cytoscape.js?

Comment: It comes from another js framework gojs, you can find the example [there](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/selectablePorts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ungrabifying disables grabbing: http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.ungrabify

Unselectifying disables selecting: http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.unselectify

`events: no` disables all events: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/events

Comment: I was already using a combinaison of these events but that's impossible to do what I explained and to trigger an event when you click on a module's port